# Is there a way to force color management in Firefox (sRGB) via CSS?

Tags: css, firefox, colors

Is there a way to force Firefox to use color management on a website via CSS or any other means?

Most browsers use color management to render images and CSS in sRGB by default. With Firefox, you need to manually enable color management. I build websites, and colors are vastly different on Firefox. I'd like a consistent, predictable rendering such that Firefox renders the same as all other browsers without requiring the user to change their about:config.

[More info on this website](https://dreamlight.com/web-color-management-for-images-and-css-colors/)

Relevant excerpt:

> Firefox 67.0.0 at least, it doesn’t color manage CSS colors. It just renders CSS colors in the monitor’s color profile. This results in CSS colors blowing out into over-saturated reds and greens when viewed on wide-gamut monitors. Firefox does support full web color management, including rendering CSS colors in sRGB and honoring ICC v4 color profiles, but it must be manually enabled using the following steps.

[image: Example of colors rendering differently in Firefox (not sRGB)]